# Restarting the app when power button is clicked even after the app is killed from recent application tray

Tags: android

I am new android I want to implement in my that when I press power button I need to open the app but the app is killed in the background from recent app tray. I am trying all the solutions which I got but I didnt get solution

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"main Activity run",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent = new Intent(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PowerService.class));
        startService(intent);*/
//     /*   new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"service run",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PowerService.class));
                startService(intent);
//            }
//        });
//*/

//        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PowerService.class);
//        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
//
//    
//


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {




        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside mainactivity onStart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside mainactivity onResume",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside mainactivity onRestart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside mainactivity onDestroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"service run",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PowerService.class));
        startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside mainactivity onStop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Service.class

```
public class PowerService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter filter;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        cpuWakeLock.acquire();
        registerReciver();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PowerService getService() {
            return PowerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("inside powerservice onUnbind");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside powerservice onUnbind",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("inside powerservice onRebind");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside powerservice onRebind",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        System.out.println("inside powerservice onStart");

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        //registerReciver();
        System.out.println("inside powerservice onDestroy");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside powerservice ondestroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startService(new Intent(this, PowerService.class));
        super.onDestroy();



    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        /*registerReciver();
        startService(new Intent(this,PowerService.class));*/
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside powerservice onTaskRemoved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this,AppReciever.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);*/
      /*  Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(this,PowerService.class);
        restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartPendingIntent);


        startService(new Intent(this,PowerService.class));*/
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    public void registerReciver()
    {
        filter= new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED);
         mReceiver = new AppReciever();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReciever

```
public class AppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.e("LOB", "onReceive");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Toast.makeText(context,"inside ACTION_SCREEN_OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
            Log.e("Screen ", "shutdown now");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here

            Log.e("Screen ", "awaked now");
            Toast.makeText(context,"inside ACTION_SCREEN_ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.e("LOB", "userpresent");
            Toast.makeText(context,"inside ACTION_USER_PRESENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent ii = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
            ii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(ii);
            wasScreenOn = true;
            //  Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);


        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"inside ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("LOB", "userpresent");
            Intent ii = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
            ii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(ii);
        }




       /* Log.v("#@%@%#", "Power button is pressed.");

        Toast.makeText(context, "power button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    }


}
```

Manifestfile

```
package="com.benayah.app.sampleapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".PowerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:process=":my_process"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong in my code and I need to run the service in background to check for the screen on even after the app is killed in background because now when I killed app I couldn't restart my app but if I didn't kill the it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use following might be helpfull...

***in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intent= new Intent(context, ActivitySample.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You below might be helpfull...

**In Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

---

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int countPowerOff=0;
private Activity activity=null;
public MyReceiver (Activity activity)
{
this.activity=activity;
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Log.v("onReceive", "Power button is pressed.");

  Toast.makeText(context, "power button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();

 if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
 {
countPowerOff++;    
 } 
 else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
 {
  if(countPowerOff==5)
  {
      Intent i =new Intent(activity,NewActivity.class);
      activity.startActivity(i);
   }
}

}
```

And,

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver (this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know to monitor the power button is by listening to the **ScreenOn** and **ScreenOff** events. So you can try to write a service that is listening to ScreenOn or ScreenOff and then each time that this event is firing you can launch the desired app.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenOnOffService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class ScreenOnOffService extends Service {

    private ScreenOnOffReceiver mScreenReceiver;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerScreenStatusReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterScreenStatusReceiver();
    }

    private void registerScreenStatusReceiver() {
        mScreenReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterScreenStatusReceiver() {
        try {
            if (mScreenReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<service android:name="com.benayah.app.sampleapp.ScreenOnOffService" />
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

(here you need to put the package name of the app that you want to launch)
in my example i put your package name: **com.benayah.app.sampleapp**

```
public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d("StackOverflow", "Screen Off");
            startApp(context);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.d("StackOverflow", "Screen On");
            startApp(context);
        }
    }

    private void startApp(Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.benayah.app.sampleapp");
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```